# Strange behavior of Boolean type in c++

Tags: c++

I have the following if statement in my code:

```
~(( APQState  == dot11->tempState[0] ) &&
  ( STAQState == dot11->tempState[1] ) &&
  ( tempk1    == dot11->tempState[2] ) &&
  ( tempk2    == dot11->tempState[3] ) &&
  ( tempk3    == dot11->tempState[4] ))
```

Let say the boolean variable,

```
B = ( APQState  == dot11->tempState[0] ) &&
    ( STAQState == dot11->tempState[1] ) &&
    ( tempk1    == dot11->tempState[2] ) &&
    ( tempk2    == dot11->tempState[3] ) &&
    ( tempk3    = =dot11->tempState[4] )
```

The if statement is being evaluated even when B is true ( => ~B is false).
I checked the value of B inside the loop when it executes. 
I get B=1;

Strangely when I try to cout the value of (~B ), it shows a value of 2. ( i.e when B = 1).

Why is this happening?

Comment: All the variables inside the individual boolean expressions for e.g APQState, dot11->tempState[2] etc are integers. All the variables are declared and initialized properly

Comment: Can u put the code for if statement

Comment: Logical negation is `!B`, not `~B`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Make sure you know what you want.

`~`  is bit operator to flip all the bits.

`!` is the logic operator for "NOT".

Answer (score 1):

Change ~B to !B.
 That should hopefully work

Answer (score 1):

The tilde (~) in C++ is a [Bitwise NOT Operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_NOT#NOT).  This is different than the Logical NOT Operator (!).

`~B` does not always equal `!B`